# How to required members of a class by flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I usually define required members of a class by flow like the below.

```
// @flow    
type Required = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
}

class User {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  middleName: string
  age: number

  constructor(params: Required) {
    this.firstName= params.firstName
    this.lastName= params.lastName
  }
}

export default User
```

But in this way, I have to define types of required members twice.
Any other efficient ways?

**Edit**
After thinking for a while, I'm feeling my question is kind of wired...
I think I can't ignore defining a type of parameters in a constructor.

Comment: Cant you just mark optional `?` properties?

Comment: To middleName and age? I don't know how it helps though...